# How to change the message when a form input doesn't match the pattern parameter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, form-for, form-with

A `pattern` argument can be provided to a form field as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47998352/5783745)

Example (regex from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41111555/regex-pattern-with-form-for-ruby-on-rails))

```
<%= f.text_field :username, pattern: "([A-Za-z0-9\-\_]+)" %>
```

When the regex is not adhered to, a message is displayed. E.g.:

[image]

How can that message be customised?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `pattern` attribute is actually a HTML spec, not a Rails thing. You can use the `title` attribute to give users a hint on to what format is expected.

```
<%= f.text_field :username, pattern: "([A-Za-z0-9\-\_]+)",
                            title: "A username can only contain letters, numbers, hyphens and underscores" %>
```

Find more information here: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#the-pattern-attribute

Comment: Thanks for explaining that, I really couldn't figure out why `pattern` seemed to be missing from `form_for` rails guides/docs. I will know for next time now